# How to reduce memory and get rid of vue reactivity?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, reactive-programming

I have a problem that `Vue's` `observer` and `reactive` components are taking a lot of memory on runtime. As an example: [Memory allocation on DevTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usUlt.png).
Is there a way to detach observable and make objects not reactive?
Or maybe there is something else to drastically reduce memory usage?

```
export class Entity {
    public Id: number;
    public Array: EntityArray[] | undefined;
    public CreatedBy: string;
    public CreatedOn: Date;
    public ModifiedBy: string;
    public ModifiedOn: Date;

    constructor(p?: IEntity) {
        this.Id = p ? p.Id : 0;
        this.Array = p && p.Array ? p.Array.map((m: IEntityArray) => new EntityArray(m)) : [];
        this.CreatedBy = p ? p.CreatedBy : '';
        this.CreatedOn = p ? p.CreatedOn : new Date();
        this.ModifiedBy = p ? p.ModifiedBy : '';
        this.ModifiedOn = p ? p.ModifiedOn : new Date();
    }
```

I am initializing `Array` here and it is `extended` by another entity which is being initialized in `Vue` component's `beforeMount()` method. I assume this Array object is the main problem that actually consumes a lot of memory, since it might have thounsands of items.
I also might be wrong about this whole memory thoughts. Anyone is welcome for insights and solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Freeze your array with Object.freeze(). this will force Vue to not make the array reactive.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods